# Inconsistent null pointer exceptions

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to read a .json file from the devices external directory.

I have a class called ExternalFile which is used to read in a file and return the contents as a string.

Here is the class:

```
public class ExternalFile
{
final String EXTERNAL_STORAGE = Evironment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
final String FIRSTDROID_DIRECTORY = EXTERNAL_STORAGE + "/firstdroid/";
final String SALES_DIRECTORY = FIRSTDROID_DIRECTORY + "sales/";
final String REFERENCE_DIRECTORY = FIRSTDROID_DIRECTORY + "reference/";

public String readFile(String direcectory, String fileName)
{
    BufferedReader br;
    StringBuilder sBuffer;
    File JSON;
    String line;
    String retVal = null;

    try
    {
        sBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        JSON = new File(direcectory, fileName);

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSON));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sBuffer.append(line);
            sBuffer.append('\n');
        }

        retVal = sBuffer.toString();

        Log.d("File Results: ", retVal);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("readJSON", e.getMessage());
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

}

When i use this class to read a "login.json" file, it works fine. However when I use the class to read a "contacts.json" file, eclipse warns: 
"Null pointer access: The variable readJSON can only be null at this location".

```
    private void getContactNames()
{
    // File jsonCustomers;
    // BufferedReader br= null;
    // StringBuilder sb = null;
    // String line;
    String result;

    ExternalFile readJSON = null;

    try
    {
            result = readJSON.readFile(REFERENCE_DIRECTORY, "contacts.json");

        // pass through the json string
        readNames(result, "contact");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        messageBox("getCustomerNames", e.toString());
    }
}
```

the only difference is that I pass in "contacts.json" instead of "login.json"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse warns if you are using a **variable without intializing** it. In your code, you have `readJSON` declared but initialized to `null`. Right after that its been used inside the `try` block which will definitely cause NPE

```
ExternalFile readJSON = null; //--> you have not intialized readJSON 
try
{
     result = readJSON.readFile(REFERENCE_DIRECTORY, "contacts.json");
              ^^^^^^^^
              null access here
```